# How to create image gallery in ASP.NET MVC3 with jquerymobile?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, jquery-mobile

i have develop a Jquerymobile applicataion in MVC3(Razor) it is working fine in mobile devices and desctop.Now i want create image gallery in this app that is when i open the app in Iphone then i get the images from Iphone gallery for uploading..Please help me how can i get all images gallery in Iphone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a google [ other search engines available ]  search for html image gallery, jquery gallery  etc should yeild quite good results for displaying a gallery.   however if you want the photo from the phone itself then you need something like phonegap and create an application for a phone so that you can access the phone itself.

there is no way for a website to access iphones files, hence the reason why upload boxes are disabled when you visit websites.

the other options is to hook through facebook and allow users to pick a photo from the ONLINE content, that can then be passed over, however this is theory and you need to actually create something, anything  and then maybe get guidance when you are stuck, or have problems.

Comment: Hi...Thank you minus for giving a good post,can you give me any sample link please...

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk   and some research i generally dont use samples so wouldent know of any phonegap.com and jquerymobile.com are a good start